# 1 control group vs. 2 treatments: one ANOVA or two t-tests?

Tags: anova, t-test, multiple-comparisons

I have 3 groups, one control group and two treatment groups that have nothing to do with each other. I just want to see if any of those 2 treatment are different from the control group.

Textbooks say 3 groups or more, use ANOVA to avoid type-1 errors.

But I just don't understand why that applies here. On the one hand, it's only 2 t-tests so doesn't seem like the chance of error is greatly increased. And on the other hand, being that have no interest in differences between the treatment groups, by doing an ANOVA can it not be misleading? (if the two treatments are different from each other but not from the control).

So, should I do an ANOVA and if the means are different perform a "Dunnett's"?
Or just do the 2 t-tests?

Comment: The null hypothesis of the global F-test from ANOVA is of no importance here, so there is no reason to run an F-test first and then, depending on its "answer", dig deeper. If you want to test the two working hypotheses "First treatment is systematically different from control" and "Second treatment is systematically different from control", then the two t-tests might be the best way to go (depending on groups sizes etc.)

Comment: By "systematically" I mean "on average" here. Wasn't too clear.

Comment: You can go straight to [Dunnett's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett%27s_test) if you want to control the family-wise error rate; or, as @Michael says, do two t-tests, if you want to control the individual error rates for each.

Comment: Will you be making any inferences of the kind, "A-control was significant while B-control was not significant and therefore there is a difference between A and B"? If so, then Dunnett's or two t-test are definitely not sufficient for your analysis.

Comment: Note that the two treatments *cannot* be "different from each other but not from the control", although you *could* find a pattern 'significant' contrasts that logically necessitates there are some type I or type II errors (more [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32840/how-to-interpret-a-post-hoc-tukeys-test/32846#32846), if you're interested).

Comment: What if you have more than one control? I have a case where I need to compare Controls 1 and 2 vs. Treatments 3, 4 and 5 (five different ways to preserve meat). The question is, of course, if the treatments do better than the controls (i.e. standard/classic procedures vs. new procedures). Any advice on the best way to proceed? Cheers,
Felipe.

Answer (score 4):

You don't *have* to run an ANOVA first, but most people do out of habit.  (Whether reviewers will give you a hard time about not having done so is a separate issue.)  Note that the original [Dunnett's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett%27s_test) required that the conditions have equal $n$s.  The test has since been generalized, so it is fine if you do not have equal $n$s, just be sure you are running the right test (and citing it properly).  You can also run two t-tests instead of either an ANOVA or Dunnett's test, but if you want to control for [type I error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_error#Type_I_error) inflation, you will need to use the [Bonferroni correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) as your tests would not be independent.

Comment: Perhaps worth emphasizing that using the Bonferroni correction on the two pre-selected t-tests would be a conservative way to control family-wise Type I error, & that Dunnett's test has higher power.

Answer (score -1):

If you have three groups you should do an ANOVA (after checking assumptions of normality etc of course) which will test if the three groups differ overall. If that is the case you can then either do contrasts or post-hoc tests to test your hypotheses directly, e.g. does group 1 differ from group 2. How to do contrasts or post-hoc tests depends on the software you use (e.g. R, SPSS etc).

Comment: Hello JolJols, thank you for your comment. I can do post-hocs on SPSS and Dunnett's on GraphPad. 

So assuming you are correct, I now am sure of what to do. But, to be honest, I still don't understand why it is more correct to use ANOVA instead of 2 t-tests in this case. I mean, I don't want to sound stubborn or plain stupid, I'd really like to understand this. Because, if I test 3groups for any kind o difference between them,I can see why the ANOVA. If I test many treatments vs a control, I can also see why the ANOVA, but 2 treatmentsvs1 contrl it still seems like the t-test could be the way.

Comment: Although advisable, it is not necessary to do the ANOVA first as long as when one uses a Bonferroni correction on the t-tests to control for the type I error inflation, or use the less conservative Dunnett's test. Nevertheless, I would suggest still doing the ANOVA first as this is how most people would use in the case of three or more groups.

Comment: @JolJols: Just doing it as a kind of warm up? And then  using Dunnett's test for the analysis you're really interested in?

Comment: The point is that the composite test - reject either null hypothesis only after a significant ANOVA _and_ a significant Dunnett's - is unnecessarily conservative; Dunnett's test already controls the family-wise error rate for the pre-specified comparisons of treatments with a control.

Comment: I agree @Scortchi, thanks for pointing this out again.

Comment: Thank you far all your answers/comments so far. 

At first it seemed like I got some mixed opinions.

Still, and correct me if I'm wrong, I believe the main message is that in such a scenario (1 Ctrl vs 2 Trt.) it would be OK to perform either the ANOVA coupled with the Dunnett's post analysis or the 2 individual t-tests with a Bonferroni correction. However, ANOVA+Dunnett's is a more direct way to find my answer and Dunnett's has a higher power.

Comment: @user34963: For *those two comparisons* either (1) use Dunnett's alone if you want to control the family-wise error rate for both together, or (2) use two t-tests without Bonferroni correction if you want to control the comparison-wise error rates for each separately. There is no need to also perform an ANOVA, & the procedure "perform Dunnett's test at a significance level of 5% if the ANOVA is significant at 5%" has a size of less than 5%. (Note this is about what's best in principle rather than what makes a great deal of difference in practice.)

Comment: Scortchi, what do you mean by performing Dunnett's alone, without doing an ANOVA at all? I ask because I always thought of it as a post-ANOVA analysis.
Also, consider this real case of mine: the ANOVA says no differences. The Dunnett's says only the first of the two treatments differs from the control. The t-test also says the first differs from the control (p=0.03) BUT applying the Bonferroni correction (0.05/2= 0.025) then it isn't anymore. So... what should I consider in this case? ANOVA=NO, Dunnett=YES, t-test= YES and NO.

Comment: Any comments on my case?

Comment: The Bonferroni correction is quite conservative, try using the Holm-Bonferroni correction. I would state both the ANOVA and the Dunnett's test/t.test with Holm correction and explain those results, thus also why the ANOVA may not have been significant.

Comment: @user34963: What comparisons do you want to make? At what level do you want to control the error rate?

Comment: I really just want to know if any of the treatments differ from the control. It's as simple as this. Regarding the second question, I wouldn't know how to answer that.