# Should I use t-test or ANOVA+post hoc (two different treatments and a control)

Tags: anova, t-test, biostatistics, post-hoc, bonferroni

I have been working with ice algaes,and Im looking on their fattyacids. 
Here is a bit about the experimental design.

I have one treatment area, cleared, where I have removed all snow. 
I have another treatment area, shaded, where I have shaded an area with a tarpaulin. Finally I have the control area, where no snow was removed.
Over a time period of 14 days, I took icecore samples every sampling day (5 sampling days).
Im interested in if there is a difference between control and cleared on day 14 (as an example), and between control and shaded. Im not interested in the difference between the two treatments.

Can I do a t-test? So on day 14, I do a t-test between my values from the treated-control, and then control-shaded. 
I know that I actually have more than two groups, but Im not interested in comparing the different treatment groups, and its only ONE more test I do. So I dont know how big of a problem a type-I error is here. 
Or can I do it, and then apply a Bonferroni ?

OR, should I do an ANOVA+posthoc with both the two treatments and the control.

The problem is that when I do t-test I get signficant different between control and cleared, which im looking for, but when I do ANOVA I dont.

Comment: Does http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78324/1-control-group-vs-2-treatments-one-anova-or-two-t-tests-3-or-more-groups?rq=1 help?