# Three treatment groups vs one control group - only interested in comparing each treatment group separately to control - best test/follow-up test?

Tags: anova, t-test, post-hoc, contrasts, control-group

I have an analysis in which I have three treatment groups each assigned to a (different) experimental condition, and one group assigned to a control condition. I am interested in whether any/each of the treatment groups differ on the DV from the control group. I'm not interested in whether the treatment groups differ from each other. I'm wondering what the best test is here?

My professor has suggested a one-way ANOVA, without getting into what tests (planned contrasts or post-hoc tests) I should use to follow up the omnibus test.

If I use planned contrasts, I don't think I can compare each treatment group separately to the control group? AFAIK I would have to do something like compare the three treatment groups simultaneously/as a chunk to the control, and then compare them to each other, which is not what I'm interested in. Is that right?

If I use post-hoc tests, my understanding is that all groups will be compared to all other groups (I think seven comparisons), and the necessary adjustments for multiple comparisons will weaken my power more than is necessary, given that I'm only interested in three comparisons.

Can I follow up the ANOVA with t-tests just for the comparisons I'm interested in, and apply a Bonferroni correction for the multiple comparisons? Or do I even need the ANOVA/omnibus at all if I'm doing this?

Or is there something else I should be doing?

Thanks for any help for what I realise is a very basic question.

EDIT: Thanks for the responses, Dunnett's test is exactly what I need!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1 control group vs. 2 treatments: one ANOVA or two t-tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78324/1-control-group-vs-2-treatments-one-anova-or-two-t-tests) I think that covers your situation, as Dunnett's test is for handling multiple comparisons in the general case of multiple treatments against a single control. See the discussion on that page for whether prior ANOVA is necessary. It isn't technically, but reviewers might nevertheless object if you omit the preliminary ANOVA.

Answer (score 1):

Dunnett's test does exactly what you want. It is usually available in stats software as a follow-up to one-way ANOVA, but the results stand alone. The results can be interpreted without reference to the overall ANOVA results.